# Unique values simple model class within Android app

Tags: android, unique, pojo

What is the easiest way ( I prefer to work with int) to make objects in a POJO class unique? I use this class within an Android App.

Comment: Please, be more specific. You should provide relevant snippets of code, layouts, etc. Have a look at [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also, have a detailed look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

```
public class PojoClass {
    int id = UniqueId.getID();
}

public static class UniqueId {
    private final static AtomicInteger c = new AtomicInteger(0);
    public static int getID() {
        return c.incrementAndGet();
    }
}
```

Is it what you need?